# Customizing ASP.NET Core Identity Tables

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0, entity-framework-migrations

When man customize the Identity classes in asp.net core 2, the relations between tables do not create automatically.

How can I create relations between tables such a simplest way?

**User class:**

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int>
{
    // codes
}
```

**Role class:**

```
public class Role : IdentityRole<int>
{
    public Role() : base()
    {

    }
    public Role(string roleName) : base(roleName)
    {

    }
}
```

**RoleClaim class:**

```
public class RoleClaim : IdentityRoleClaim<int> { }
```

**UserClaim class:**

```
public class UserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int> { }
```

**UserLogin class:**

```
public class UserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int> { }
```

**UserRole class:**

```
public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole<int> { }
```

**UserToken class:**

```
public class UserToken : IdentityUserToken<int> { }
```

[image: custom Identity without relations between tables]

**I want to have same as this relations between my tables:**

[image: Default Identity Table]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've defined the relations of tables by writing some codes in `User`, `Role`, `UserClaim`, `UserRole`, `UserLogin`, `RoleClaim` and `UserToken` class and in `ApplicationDbContext` class.

**Role class:**

```
public class Role : IdentityRole<int>
{
    public Role() : base()
    {

    }
    public Role(string roleName) : this()
    {
        Name = roleName;
    }

    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RoleClaim> Claims { get; set; }
}
```

**RoleClaim class:**

```
public class RoleClaim : IdentityRoleClaim<int>
{
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

**User class:**

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public virtual ICollection<UserToken> UserTokens { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> Roles { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserLogin> Logins { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserClaim> Claims { get; set; }
}
```

**UserClaim class:**

```
public class UserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int>
{
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

**UserLogin class:**

```
public class UserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int>
{
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

**UserRole class:**

```
public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole<int>
{
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

**UserToken class:**

```
public class UserToken : IdentityUserToken<int>
{
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

**ApplicationDbContext class:**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, int, UserClaim, UserRole, UserLogin, RoleClaim, UserToken>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<RoleClaim>(builder =>
        {
            builder.HasOne(roleClaim => roleClaim.Role).WithMany(role => role.Claims).HasForeignKey(roleClaim => roleClaim.RoleId);
            builder.ToTable("RoleClaim");
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>(builder =>
        {
            builder.ToTable("Role");
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserClaim>(builder =>
        {
            builder.HasOne(userClaim => userClaim.User).WithMany(user => user.Claims).HasForeignKey(userClaim => userClaim.UserId);
            builder.ToTable("UserClaim");
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserLogin>(builder =>
        {
            builder.HasOne(userLogin => userLogin.User).WithMany(user => user.Logins).HasForeignKey(userLogin => userLogin.UserId);
            builder.ToTable("UserLogin");
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>(builder =>
        {
            builder.ToTable("User");
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>(builder =>
        {
            builder.HasOne(userRole => userRole.Role).WithMany(role => role.Users).HasForeignKey(userRole => userRole.RoleId);
            builder.HasOne(userRole => userRole.User).WithMany(user => user.Roles).HasForeignKey(userRole => userRole.UserId);
            builder.ToTable("UserRole");
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserToken>(builder =>
        {
            builder.HasOne(userToken => userToken.User).WithMany(user => user.UserTokens).HasForeignKey(userToken => userToken.UserId);
            builder.ToTable("UserToken");
        });
    }
}
```

You can see the result in this picture:
[image: CustomIdentityTables]

Answer (score 2):

There's generic type overloads of `IdentityDbContext`. If you're going to customize some of the classes, you have to tell Identity which entities to actually use via these overloads. Since, you're customizing pretty much everything, you'll need the most expansive overload:

```
public class MyContext : IdentityDbContext<User, CustomRole, int, CustomUserClaim, CustomUserRole, CustomUserLogin, CustomRoleClaim, CustomUserLogin>
```

Comment: I did it already but that is not enough. I found the solution!

Comment: @Roohi could you please tell me how did you do it?